# Why is this Spring Boot jar throwing an UnsupportedClassVersion error?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

I [precisely followed the steps in the tutorial at this link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/)  to create a Spring Boot web service.  I am able to run the service on my local CentOS 7 devbox when the terminal is pointed to the root directory of the uncompiled app, and I type in the following:

```
# ./gradlew clean build && java -jar build/libs/gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar
```

However, the app is throwing an error instead of loading when I `scp` the resulting `jar` to a remote CentOS 7 web server and move the `jar` to `/some/arbitrary/path/to/jar/gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar` and then `cd /some/arbitrary/path/to/jar/` and `java -jar gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar`.  **How can I resolve this error and thus be able to start the app succesfully on the remote CentOS 7 web server?**

I imagine that the error has to do with directory structure, but I just want the jar on the web server.  I do not want the un-jarred app on the server.  And the only way I know to eliminate the error would be to recreate the un-jarred app on the server.  How can I fix the problem without resorting to loading the whole un-jarred app to the server?

Here is the stack trace:

```
$ java -jar gs-actuator-service-0.1.0.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: hello/HelloWorldConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:170)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
$
```

Comment: What Spring Boot version?

Comment: @BranislavLazic Not sure.  What do I type to get that information?  I see that the devbox is running Java 8 while the server is running Java 7.  I am researching how to recompile the jar on the devbox using Java 7.

Comment: Your problem is very simple. You are using unsupported Java version. Your code is probably compiled with Java 8 compiler and ran with Java 7.

Comment: @BranislavLazic Yep. I am trying to find out how to list the jdk version installed on my devbox and then, if necessary, download version 1.7.0_75.  Then I will have to specify version to be used in compilation in order to assess whether this is the problem or not.